# What does Tomcat do under the hood to give you an implementation of DataSource

Tags: java, tomcat, datasource, jndi

From [JNDI Resources HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

```
<Context ...>
  ...
  <Resource name="jdbc/EmployeeDB"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            username="dbusername"
            password="dbpassword"
            driverClassName="org.hsql.jdbcDriver"
            url="jdbc:HypersonicSQL:database"
            maxActive="8"
            maxIdle="4"/>
  ...
</Context>
```

The type is javax.sql.DataSource and this is an interface.

The code below retrieves an instance of DataSource and get a connection out of it.

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource)
  envCtx.lookup("jdbc/EmployeeDB");

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
... use this connection to access the database ...
conn.close();
```

From [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4075805/1411701), it says the actual implementation of DataSource is up to the database vendor.

So in this example, does Tomcat use `driverClassName="org.hsql.jdbcDriver"` to return an implementation of DataSource ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat has a [connection pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html) implementation. This connection pool has an implementation of the interface DataSource. And this implementation uses the specified driver class (`org.hsql.jdbcDriver`) in order to open connections to the database.